# How to migrate Webform data from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, webforms

I have a Drupal 7 installation with the Webform module enabled. I recreated a Drupal 6 webform and now want to migrate data from the Drupal 6 installation to the Drupal 7 installation. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can migrate Drupal 6 webform data to 7 using the [Mirgrate Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_webform) module.

> It will migrate all nodes of the webform node type (with the default D6 fields using migrate_d2d backend), all the configuration* of the webform's settings, the form components, email destinations, submissions and associated submission data, in addition to any validation configuration you have (from webform_validation module). It grabs the "last downloaded" data too, in case your users were downloading sequential batches since the last time they were on the site.